# pstricks: strange behaviour using \rput* with pst-solides3d

Tags: pstricks, pst-solides3d

i got a strange behaviour using  `\rput` and `\rput*` with the package `pst-solides3d`. it concern more or less the commands `\rput` and `\psdot` in the following example

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\defFunction{cont}(u,v){u}{v}{u dup mul v dup mul add}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1)(2,2)

\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree,
linecolor=green,
base=-1 1 -1 1,
fillcolor=green!50,incolor=green!20,
function=cont,linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,
ngrid=.2 .2,
action=draw**]

\psPoint(0,0,1){P}
\psdot(P)
\rput*(P){$110$}

\psframe(-2,-1)(2,2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

1. using `\rput*` (*without* `\psdot`), there's a shift of the plot but the text is in the wrong place
2. using `\rput` (*without* `\psdot`), no shift but no text as well
3. using  `\rput` or `\rput*` with `\psdot`, the output is correct
4. if i put the `\psframe` command *before* the \psSolid command then i got a postscript error

seems rather mysterious to me. did i make something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use `\rput*` outside of the `pspicture` environment. Then you can be sure, that the commulated PostScript code is executed:

```
[ ... ]
\psPoint(0,0,1){P}
\psdot(P)
\psframe(-2,-1)(2,2)
\end{pspicture}
\rput*(P){$110$}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the package is not perfect. A simple solution is to add `\composeSolid` when there is something wrong. Try this

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\defFunction{cont}(u,v){u}{v}{u dup mul v dup mul add}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1)(2,2)

\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree,
linecolor=green,
base=-1 1 -1 1,
fillcolor=green!50,incolor=green!20,
function=cont,linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,
ngrid=.2 .2,
action=draw**]

\psPoint(0,0,1){P}
\composeSolid  %  LOOK HERE !!!!!!!!!!!
%\psdot(P)
\rput*(P){$110$}

\psframe(-2,-1)(2,2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```